# add comparison feature in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, button

i'm having a bit of trouble with adding a certain feature. i'm working on a buy/sell site and i want to be able to compare posts. here's what i have so far:

in the posts view:

```
<%= button_to "Add to Compare", :action => "addCompare" %>
```

in the corresponding controller:

```
@@a = Array.new()

def addCompare
   @@a << Post.id
end
```

so, all i want to do is add the post's id to the array @@a. when i test this, i click on the "Add to Compare" button and I'm welcomed with this:

Template is missing

Missing template posts/addCompare with {:locale=>[:en, :en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:rxml, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :erb]} in view paths "/home/mja32/470repo/traders/app/views", "/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/devise-1.4.2/app/views"

So I guess it's trying to redirect to a view. How do I prevent it from doing this? All I want this button to do is to add the post's id to the array and nothing more.

Thanks in advance,

Matt

Comment: `addCompare`, `@@a = Array.new()` ewwww. It's not ruby!

Comment: you should really need to read some tutorials both about Ruby and Rails...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, storing persistent data in a controller's class variable isn't going to work the way you want it to. There's no guarantee that `@@a` will be the same array on your next `addCompare` call; for example, your next `addCompare` call could be handled by a different process. Also, what happens if two different clients call `addCompare`? Do you really want to mix their data together in one pile? Probably not. Your first task is to replace `@@a` with a real per-user persistent store.

If you want to return nothing at all from your controller, just do this at the end of your [controller method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render):

```
render :nothing => true, :status => :ok
```

That will tell Rails that something has already been rendered so it doesn't need to try the default rendering action (which is to render the `posts/addCompare` view) and returns nothing more than a 200 status code to the client.

Once that's in place, you'll probably want to AJAXify your button with [`:remote => true`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to):

> `:remote` - If set to true, will allow the Unobtrusive JavaScript drivers to control the submit behaviour. By default this behaviour is an ajax submit.

So this:

```
<%= button_to "Add to Compare", { :action => "addCompare" }, { :remote => true } %>
```

Note that `button_to` looks like this:

```
button_to(name, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

and that `:action` is for `options` but `:remote` is for `html_options` so you have to explicitly set up the hashes with `{}`; you could just wrap the `options` in braces:

```
<%= button_to "Add to Compare", { :action => "addCompare" }, :remote => true %>
```

but I prefer the consistency of wrapping them both by hand.

Comment: thanks mu. you bring up a good point. i was so worried about getting the basic functionality down that i hadn't thought about the details yet. sorry if i'm being stupid, but i added the above line of code and i get a blank page. i'd like it to stay on the same post page.

Comment: hmmm thanks but still a blank page after i click on the button

Comment: @Matt: Are you including all the usual `rails.js` preamble?

Comment: i've got <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %> in view/layouts/application.html.erb. Is this correct? It seems as if we're opening up a can of worms here and I apologize for this. I've been pushed into the deep end without knowing how to swim. So, short answer to your question is no.

Comment: Sigh. I am in too much of a hurry today and being sloppy. `button_to` takes two hash arguments and you want `:remote` in the second one, see my updated update. My apologies for the confusion, I should be a bit more careful.